# Grouping array with map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I want to group array of objects by its key,

The Original form;

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'karthik'},
    {'id': 1, 'age': 31},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'ramesh'},
    {'id': 2,  'age': 22}
];
```

To transform in to,

```
groupedData = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'karthik', 'age': 31},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'ramesh', 'age': 22}
];
```

What I tried,

```
this.data.map(item => item.id)
        .filter((item, index, all) => all.indexOf(item) === index);
        console.log(this.data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce` instead of `map`.

```
const groupedData = Object.values(this.data.reduce((a, { id, ...r }) => ({ ...a, [id]: { ...(a[id] || { id }), ...r }}), {}));
```

How this works:

Firstly, using `reduce` is far easier than any `map` solution because it allows us to have an accumulator value `a`.

Then, we extract the `id`, and the `r`est of the properties (because we don't know what they're called).

We return `a`, with the property keyed with the *value* of `id` being either the existing property or a new one with `id`, as well as the rest of the properties.

Comment: please explain what is it doin?

Comment: Edited @kartik, does that help?

Comment: No problem @ChrisY, always glad to help. [Here](https://codeburst.io/learn-understand-javascripts-reduce-function-b2b0406efbdc)'s some reading material on `reduce` to help you understand how the code works a little better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to create an object ( a table ) for each id.

```
const groupMap = data.reduce((group, currentData) => {
    const id = currentData['id']
    group[id] = { ...(group[id] || {}), ...currentData }
    return group
} ,{})
```

what this returns is something like:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "karthik",
    "age": 31
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ramesh",
    "age": 22
  }
}
```

`group[id] = { ...(group[id] || {}), ...currentData }` is basically "if you already saw this id, just merge the previous data with the current data"

then you can get the final result calling `Object.values`

```
const groupedData = Object.values(groupMap)
```

which just get the values of the object created above.

Comment: you can copy and paste in your browser's console, and see all the steps.

Comment: please explain what is it doin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = data.reduce((total, current, index) => {
for(let key in current) total[index][key] = current[key]
return total
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you)

```
    function mergeobj(arrofobj) {
 arrofobj.map((item, index) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrofobj.length; i++) {
        if(i==index)continue;
        if (item['id'] == arrofobj[i]['id']) {
            item = Object.assign(item, arrofobj[i]);
            arrofobj.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
        }
    }
    return item;
})
return arrofobj; }
```